# How to validate user login credentials and Google reCAPTCHA response in a PHP if else statement

Tags: php, authentication, if-statement, recaptcha

I am trying to validate my users email, password and the Google reCAPTCHA response on my websites login page. I can validate the email and password using this code:

```
if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "Email, password and reCAPTCHA validated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Email, password or reCAPTCHA not entered or incorrect";
}
```

However, when I change the first line of code to also validate the reCAPTCHA response it still only validates the email and password. This is the code I have to try and also validate the reCAPTCHA response:

```
if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) && grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"?

Comment: Isn't grecaptcha.getresponse() a *JavaScript* function? (You can't mix the two like this...)  Dump your POST data in PHP and see if it's there....  I think the POST array should contain a variable "g-recaptcha-response", per the docs: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have updated the post

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey what do you mean by dump my post data in PHP and see if it's there?

Comment: At the top of your PHP file, you do var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST) to see what's in the POSTed form from PHP's point of view.  Basic debugging ... see, for example: http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/

Comment: Please paste the code where you are validating it. this code is for resultset that is retrieved from database.

Comment: @MurtazaBhurgri the email and password is validated from the database with no problems. It's the && grecaptcha.getResponse() == "" that is not working.